# Как написать скрипт php, который откроет текстовый файл?

Tags: php

Пробовал в папке сервера разместить файл с вот таким содержимым, файл file.txt не открывается.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('file.txt')){
$file = fopen('file.txt','r');
}else{
echo("Ошибка открытия файла: файл не существует");
}
?>
```

Вообще может я глубоко заблуждался? В моих представлениях должно было появиться окно текстового редактора. Если Это не так, прошу пояснить как это работает.

Comment: В вашем понимании "открыть" это запустить текстовой редактор и открыть в нем текстовой файл?

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь открыть файл, находящийся в одной папке с исполняемым скриптом. Перепроверьте пути еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Окно текстового редактора появляться не будет.
Если у вас маленький файл и есть желание увидеть его содержимое, то можно использовать [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Ваш ответ ничем не отличается от варианта вопрошающего, кроме использования другой функции, выполняющей то же самое.